# Custom User Management for Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, user-management

For a current project my team is working on, we have decided to go with AzureB2C as the authentication method for the ReactJS application we are building. I understand how we can make use of custom policies for things such as Sign Up, Sign in, Password Reset etc...

However what I am trying to workout is how we can surface up a more general user management interface for users of our application, that would allow them to perform tasks such as creating user accounts, deleting, updating profiles and resetting passwords.

- Does all of this have to be done through the AzureB2C interface? Or would we have to build this interface using Azure B2C API's?
- Has this been done before? If so where can I buy it? :D My search to date suggest it hasn't...

Comment: Pretty much all here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not product that you can buy that enables User Management for B2C tenants. 
 If you are not enabling your users to access the Azure portal (and i agree you shouldnt) then you will need to either 1) Build in the User Management features in your app UI (in an admin role) or 2) Build a separate "Admin" app that contains the user management features you need, my organization had a similar need and chose #2

Comment: Yeah, thanks for confirming, that's what I thought would be the case. Did your organisation just make use of the standard API's for option #2? Were there any "gotchas" to make note of?

Comment: Yes, standard APIs (Azure AD Graph has to be used, MS Graph not supported... yet), no major gotchas, fairly straightforward